# Restore build dependencies from JFrog artifactory in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I am trying to build a solution in Azure DevOps that has all its dependent nuget packages stored in an artifactory behind firewall. I am using the following link as guide:

[Artifactory Azure DevOps Extension](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Azure+DevOps+Extension)

But I am having error while configuring the artifactory service connection. Here goes the attached image.
[image: Service Connection Error]

The URL cannot be provided here, the artifactory resides behind the company firewall. I am using the url and artifactory api key to establish the connection.

How to create a service connection in Azure DevOps to artifactory that resides behind a firewall ?

Comment: You need to make sure that Azure DevOps can communicate with Artifactory through the firewall

Answer (score 0):

Agree with **Dror**, you should at least make sure Azure DevOps Service can communicate with your Artifactory behind the firewall. For more details you can refer to [Azure DevOps domains to allow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops#azure-devops-domains-to-allow)
:

To ensure your organization works with any existing firewall or IP restrictions, ensure that `dev.azure.com` and `*dev.azure.com` are open. I used F12 and found the request url is `https://dev.azure.com/...` when clicking the **Verify** button.

So I suggest you can add these two into the Whitelist of your firewall.